# Speed up or vectorize pandas apply function - require a conditional application of a function

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, python-multiprocessing, data-science

I want to apply a function row-wise to a dataframe that looks like this:

```
name  value 

'foo' 2
'bar' 4
'bar' 3
'foo' 1
  .   .
  .   .
  .   .
'bar' 8
```

Speed is important to me since I am operating on multiple 90GB datasets, so I have been attempting to vectorize the following operation for use in df.apply:

Conditioned on the 'name', I want to plug 'value' into a separate function, perform some arithmetic on the result, and write to a new column 'output'. Something like,

```
funcs = {'foo': <FunctionObject>, 'bar': <FunctionObject>}

def masterFunc(row):
    correctFunction = funcs[row['name']]
    row['output'] = correctFunction(row['value']) + 3*row['value']

df.apply(masterFunc, axis=1).
```

In my real problem, I have 32 different functions that could apply to the 'value' based on the 'name'. Each of those individual functions (fooFunc, barFunc, zooFunc, etc) are already vectorized; they are scipy.interp1d functions built like this:

```
separateFunc = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(x-coords=[2, 3, 4], y-coords=[3, 5, 7])
#separateFunc is now a math function, y=2x-1. use case:
y = separateFunc(3.5) # y == 6
```

However, I am not sure how I can vectorize the masterFunc itself. It seems like choosing which function to 'pull out' to apply to the 'value' is very expensive, because it requires a memory access at each iteration (with my current method of storing the functions in hashtables). However, the alternative just seems to be a bunch of if-then statements, which also seems impossible to vectorize. How can I speed this up?

Actual code, with repetitive parts removed for brevity:

```
interpolationFunctions = {}
#the 'interpolate.emissionsFunctions' are a separate function which does some scipy stuff
interpolationFunctions[2] = interpolate.emissionsFunctions('./roadtype_2_curve.csv')
interpolationFunctions[3] = interpolate.emissionsFunctions('./roadtype_3_curve.csv')

def compute_pollutants(row):
    funcs = interpolationFunctions[row['roadtype']]
    speed = row['speed']
    length = row['length']
    row['CO2-Atm'] = funcs['CO2-Atm'](speed)*length*speed*0.00310686368
    row['CO2-Eq'] = funcs['CO2-Eq'](speed)*length*speed*0.00310686368
    return row
```

Comment: By keeping your functions separate like this, there is little to be done other that using apply.  However, depending on what the functions are, you may be able to do something via `numba` using `jit`.  If you are comfortable sharing the actual functions, you should do so.  You could cythonize as well, but again, that depends on the functions (I think).  Even sharing 2 or 3 of them so we can build a demonstration.

Comment: Hi @piRSquared thanks for the response! My separate functions are scipy interpolate functions (added in the original question). Can I do anything with that?

Comment: I don't see any functions.

Comment: sorry, just finished adding. each of the separateFuncs are pre-built off of pre-existing data; scipy.interpolate returns them as function objects.

Comment: Are all your functions like this?  Show me a couple more.  You're likely not going to get a simple answer with generic function objects.  But we might be able to do something with the functions themselves.  I can certainly rewrite an interpolation function.  Question is, can we write one such that it is dynamic.  Maybe, I need to see more of your other functions.

Comment: every one of my functions are like this, just built off of different x coordinates and y coordinates. they have been pre-built in a separate task, and passed over to this task. i am adding the actual code to the main post now:

Comment: Well that's a bummer.  Then you are going to have split this out with a multiprocessing module.  I could fumble an answer together, but lets put a new tag to solicit more views.

Comment: for sure. thanks so much for your help so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempted to create a reproducible example that should generalize to your problem. You can run the code with different row sizes to compare the results between different methods, it also shouldn't be difficult to extend one of these methods to using cython or multiprocessing for even faster speeds. You mentioned that your data is quite large, I haven't tested the memory usage for each of the methods so it's worth trying out on your own machine.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time as t

# Example Functions
def foo(x):
    return x + x

def bar(x):
    return x * x

# Example Functions for multiple columns
def foo2(x, y):
    return x + y

def bar2(x, y):
    return x * y

# Create function dictionary
funcs = {'foo': foo, 'bar': bar}
funcs2 = {'foo': foo2, 'bar': bar2}

n_rows = 1000000
# Generate Sample Data
names = np.random.choice(list(funcs.keys()), size=n_rows)
values = np.random.normal(100, 20, size=n_rows)
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['name'] = names
df['value'] = values

# Create copy for comparison using different methods
df_copy = df.copy()

# Modified original master function
def masterFunc(row, functs):
    correctFunction = funcs[row['name']]
    return correctFunction(row['value']) + 3*row['value']

t1 = t.time()
df['output'] = df.apply(lambda x: masterFunc(x, funcs), axis=1)
t2 = t.time()
print("Time for all rows/functions: ", t2 - t1)


# For Functions that Can be vectorized using numpy
t3 = t.time()
output_dataframe_list = []
for func_name, func in funcs.items():
    df_subset = df_copy.loc[df_copy['name'] == func_name,:]
    df_subset['output'] = func(df_subset['value'].values) + 3 * df_subset['value'].values
    output_dataframe_list.append(df_subset)

output_df = pd.concat(output_dataframe_list)

t4 = t.time()
print("Time for all rows/functions: ", t4 - t3)


# Using a for loop over numpy array of values is still faster than dataframe apply using
t5 = t.time()
output_dataframe_list2 = []
for func_name, func in funcs2.items():
    df_subset = df_copy.loc[df_copy['name'] == func_name,:]
    col1_values = df_subset['value'].values
    outputs = np.zeros(len(col1_values))
    for i, v in enumerate(col1_values):
        outputs[i] = func(col1_values[i], col1_values[i]) + 3 * col1_values[i]

    df_subset['output'] = np.array(outputs)
    output_dataframe_list2.append(df_subset)

output_df2 = pd.concat(output_dataframe_list2)

t6 = t.time()
print("Time for all rows/functions: ", t6 - t5)
```